# Combine multiple ffmpeg commands into one

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to automate some steps at work. I've been tasked to add a disclaimer at the beginning of our lecture videos, trim the lecture videos a few seconds at the beginning and end (with fade-in and out), and add a logo on top of our lecture videos. I can do that but unfortunately only in separate steps. What I want to achieve is to do all steps with one command.

I was able to combine some of the commands but not one with a following one.

I don't know if I'm expecting too much of FFmpeg.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Here my code:

**Creating a disclaimer with fade-in and out**

```
ffmpeg -i media/disclaimer.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=fps=30,loop=loop=450:size=30:start=0[v0];[v0]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=14:d=1" disclaimer.mp4
```

**Add an empty audio track to the disclaimer**

```
ffmpeg -i disclaimer.mp4 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -shortest -y disclaimer_final.mp4
```

**Add logo to lecture video**

```
ffmpeg -i lecture.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=0:0" lecture_logo.mp4
```

**Trim lecture video**

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i lecture_logo.mp4 -to 00:45:32 -async 1 lecture_out.mp4
```

**Add fade-in and out to lecture video**

```
ffmpeg -i lecture_out.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=2,fade=t=out:st=2730:d=2;[0:a]afade=t=in:st=0:d=2,afade=t=out:st=2730:d=2" lecture_final.mp4
```

**And finally concatenate the disclaimer and lecture video**

```
ffmpeg -i disclaimer_final.mp4 -i lecture_final.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [outv] [outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" final.mp4
```

Comment: In Trim lecture video, since you have set input seek of 5 seconds, the `to` will end video at 45m37s of the source. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, I've put it in as an example. Our lecturers leave space at the beginning and at the end, so the video needs to be trimmed. These two timestamps will be varying from lecture to lecture.

Comment: My point is that the `to` value in your trim command won't refer to the timestamp in the source file - I hope you're aware of that.

Comment: Oo, I see now. In this case, the total duration would be 2727, and in order to apply a fade-out of 2 seconds, it would have to be placed at 2725 in my fifth step. Thanks for pointing that out. Any hope for combining all into one?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it but had to make a compromise. Instead of generating a disclaimer and adding a dummy audio track as shown in the first two steps, I'll be using its mp4 output. The remaining four steps have been merged to the command below:

```
ffmpeg -i lecture.mp4 -i logo.png -i disclaimer.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=start=5:end=2732,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
[0:a]atrim=start=5:end=2732,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; \
[v0][1:v]overlay=0:0[vv0]; \
[vv0]fade=t=in:st=0:d=2,fade=t=out:st=2725:d=2[vvv0]; \
[a0]afade=t=in:st=0:d=2,afade=t=out:st=2725:d=2[aa0]; \
[2:v][2:a][vvv0][aa0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vv][aa]" \
-map [vv] -map [aa] output.mp4
```